# Different view for Ajax postback without duplicating controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an "Add to Cart" button that if the browser supports JS + Ajax (and doesn't have it turned off) it POSTS using Ajax back to the site, however if they don't support it, or have it turned off it does the manual style POST.

What I am hoping to accomplish is two views - one when the user posts back using a regular POST and one when it comes from a AJAX POST. That way I can show an in-line message (partial) or a full screen.

I would prefer not having to duplicate the controller/action code twice, it just seems non-elegant.

Is there any recommended solutions or patterns for this type of issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John,

You can use the IsAjaxRequest method on the request to determine this. You would apply it to your scenario thusly:

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(YourCartViewmodel cartViewmodel)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         // do the standard/common db stuff here
         if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
         {
             return PartialView("myPartialView");
         }
         else
         {
             return View("standardView");
         }
     }
     /* always return full 'standard' postback if model error */
     return View(cartViewmodel);   
}
```

altho not perhaps giving a complete solution, this should give you a good start...

Answer (score 1):

You can have two different actions in your controller. One for regular post and one for AJAX.

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(Viewmodel vm)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         DoStuff(vm);
         return View("ViewForRegularPost");
     }
     /* error */
     return View(vm);   
}
```

and

```
public ActionResult JsonAddToCart(Viewmodel vm)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         DoStuff(vm);
         return View("ViewForJS");
     }
     /* error */
     return View(vm);     
}
```

Instead of repeating your controller code, have a separate method for actual controller code.

```
public void DoStuff(Viewmodel vm)
{
    //TODO : Actual controller code goes here
}
```

Comment: This was the pattern I was hoping to avoid (i.e having two blocks of code do really the same thing, but I think I may have to use it). I know it probably isn't but it just feels dirty having tow locations to post back to.